# Typedef gives error "no storage class or specifier"

Tags: c++

I was programming a project the other day. I'm a beginner to C++, so I don't know that much. Here's the code:

```
typedef struct notes{
int keyint;
char name;
std::string filename;
int orn; 

note;
note a0;
a0.keyint = 0;
a0.name = 'a';
a0.filename = "a0.wav";
a0.orn = 1;
```

This is very confusing.

Comment: Is this the exact code? Where is the closing `}`? Are `a0.keyint = 0;` and the lines below outside of any function?

Comment: BTW, in C++, you don't need `typedef struct`.  Remove the `typedef`.

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` for your structure.

Comment: You need to read more about `struct`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the corrected form:

```
struct Note
{
    int keyint;
    char name;
    std::string filename;
    int orn;
};

Note a0;
a0.keyint = 0;
a0.name = 'a';
a0.filename = "a0.wav";
a0.orn = 1;
```

In my style, I prefer to capitalize structure and class names.  This helps distinguish class names from variable names.

**Note:** The code should be placed inside of a function or method.  C++ doesn't allow code to be executed outside of a function.  (If your an advance C++ guru, you'll know there are ways around requiring code in functions or methods).